# Why we cannot receive emai from fabric?

Tags: google-fabric

My colleague and I have not received any emails(daily summary email and Crash report) from the fabric since December last year.but we have been received before.I checked the settings/Notifications on the fabric and they are all open.Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Is there anyone here?